# update query adding old data too even after changing id

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Create a procedure  that accepts 2 parameters represented the inv_id, and the percentage increase in price.  The pseudo function should first update the database with the new price then return the new price and the quantity on hand. 
Create a second procedure called L4Q3 that accepts the inv_id and the percentage increase in price.  The procedure will use the old procedure to display the new value of the inventory (hint: value = price X quantity on hand)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex3 (p_inv_id IN NUMBER, p_change IN NUMBER, 
p_new_price OUT NUMBER, p_qoh OUT NUMBER)
AS
v_new_price NUMBER(6,2);
v_qoh NUMBER(6,2);
BEGIN
UPDATE inventory 
SET inv_price = (SELECT inv_price + (inv_price*(p_change/100))
FROM inventory
WHERE inv_id = p_inv_id);
COMMIT;
SELECT inv_price, inv_qoh
INTO p_new_price, p_qoh
FROM inventory
WHERE inv_id = p_inv_id;
COMMIT;
v_qoh := p_qoh;
v_new_price := p_new_price;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello'||v_new_price);
END;
/ 


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE use_ex3 ( p_inv_id NUMBER, p_change NUMBER)
AS
v_new_price NUMBER(6,2);
v_qoh NUMBER(6,2);
v_value NUMBER(10,2);
BEGIN
ex3(p_inv_id, p_change, v_new_price, v_qoh);
v_value := v_new_price*v_qoh;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('value is:'||v_value);
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider converting your procedures like those below :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex3(p_inv_id    IN  inventory.inv_id%type,
                                     p_change    IN  NUMBER,
                                     p_new_price OUT inventory.inv_price%type,
                                     p_qoh       OUT inventory.inv_qoh%type) AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE inventory
     SET inv_price = inv_price * ( 1 + (p_change / 100) )
   WHERE inv_id = p_inv_id
   RETURNING inv_price, inv_qoh 
        INTO p_new_price, p_qoh;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello '|| p_new_price);
END;
/
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE use_ex3(p_inv_id inventory.inv_id%type, p_change NUMBER) AS
        v_new_price inventory.inv_price%type;
        v_qoh       inventory.inv_qoh%type;
        v_value     NUMBER(10, 2);
BEGIN
   ex3(p_inv_id, p_change, v_new_price, v_qoh);
   v_value := v_new_price * v_qoh;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('value is: '|| v_value);
END;
```

the core issue is

**missing filter `WHERE inv_id = p_inv_id` in the `UPDATE` statement.
   i.e. not restricted to only one `inv_id`**

*Moreover considering below matters will make your code better :*

- don't need a subquery for the `SET` clause, just an assignment needed as `inv_price = inv_price * ( 1 + (p_change / 100) )`
- had better defining variable types for columns as
  `inventory.<column_name>%type`
- extra local variables are not needed such as `v_new_price`, `out`
  parameters of the procedures such as `p_new_price` might be used as
  the assignment targets
- `SELECT` statement after `UPDATE` is not needed, using `RETURNING
  INTO` is enough
- don't forget to use `set serveroutput on` to print out the results
- I think it's a good habit to exclude `commit` in individual program
  units to provide transaction integrity for data consistency in the
  tables which got DML. Prefer keep only one `commit` inside the caller
  application at the end of all statements and program units.

Comment: Wrong answer, second procedure should be called `L4Q3`. Just kidding, great, detailed answer ;-)